# npm - EPERM: operation not permitted ,read On Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

I have problem when i try to run npm start

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
>       at Object.readSync (fs.js:498:3)
>       at Object.readSync (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:143:28)
>       at tryReadSync (fs.js:332:20)
>       at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:361:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:220:39)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:78:24)
>       at _next (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:98:9)
>       at C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:103:7
>       at new Promise () type: 'Error', errno: -4048, syscall: 'read', code: 'EPERM' }
>   (node:14128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
>       at Object.readSync (fs.js:498:3)
>       at Object.readSync (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:143:28)
>       at tryReadSync (fs.js:332:20)
>       at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:361:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:220:39)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:78:24)
>       at _next (C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:98:9)
>       at C:\Users\Nidhal\ReactProjects\dieton\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\worker.js:103:7
>       at new Promise ()
>   (node:14128) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:14128) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Want to create a React native project and launch an app?

Comment: Yes this what i  want  to  do

Answer (score 0):

We recommend installing `Node` and `Python2` via [`Chocolatey`](https://chocolatey.org/), a popular package manager for Windows.

1. Open an Administrator Command Prompt (right click Command Prompt and
   select "Run as Administrator"), then run the following command:

   `choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8`

If you have already installed Node on your system, make sure it is `Node 8.3` or newer. If you already have a `JDK` on your system, make sure it is `version 8` or newer.

2. `npm install -g react-native-cli`
3. Install `Android Studio`
4. Configure the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable
   [image: androidHome]
5. `react-native init YourProject`
6. `cd YourProject`
7. `react-native run-android`

[Detailed description](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) of the installation methods of installation

Comment: thank you for your answer , i was installing it this error happened when i run react-native run-android or npm start.

Comment: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:498:3)

Comment: Could you try `sudo react-native run-android` ?? after `choco install sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the few possible solution, you may try. Otherwise explain the issue in details

To access and make a change to current directory you need to run cmd as administrator.

Try to run cmd as administrator

Then do npm start, that will works in a normal console.

Otherwise-

npm cache clean --force

npm cache verify

Otherwise - You may also try to downgrade or upgrade the npm version

To uninstall:

npm uninstall npm -g

Install the Latest version:

npm install -g npm@latest

or

Install the previous version:

npm install npm@5.3 -g

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to close the IDE(VSCode/WebStorm/etc) which used to open the code files and try `npm install`.